# 2-way SSL Authentication for WCF Service

Tags: wcf, authentication, ssl-certificate

Team,

I have a WCF service. I would like to know how to implement 2-way SSL authentication for the Service.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of this it talks about using preshared certs to do SSL for WCF http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx